# Как вместо &quot; показывать "

Tags: php

```
$search = array (
         "'\"'i",                 
         "'&'i",
         "'>'i",
         "'<'i",
             "'\''i"
             );

$replace = array (
          "&quot;",
          "&amp;",
          "&gt;",
          "&lt;",
              "&apos;"
              );
```

Следующая регулярка. При обработке символов заменяет их нормально, но при выводе вместо " выводит на страницу &quot; - то есть браузер не обработал спецсимвол &quot; и вывел его как есть. Остальные выводит как нужно. Как исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо регулярки используйте: `htmlspecialchars(); htmlspecialchars_decode();`
А при выводе у вас возможно `&quot;` обрабатывается дважды, и получается `&amp;quot;` вместо `&quot;`